# Can't get CircleMapObject from Tiled fLIbGDX

Tags: libgdx

I created a TiledMap in Tiled with a few  (object)layers.
Now I wanted to use Box2D to locate, in this case the Ractangles, and put them in a Physics world so my Player can collide with them. However this worked fine for the Rectangles, but I have some problem with the Circles. Here the code I used to create boxes/Rectanles :

```
for (MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(3).getObjects()
        .getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
        Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

        new normalBox(world,map,rect);
}
```

Now I wanted to do the same thing for coins but therfore I need something like an Ellipse or a Circle. My Problem is it doesnt seem to find any Circles in the TiledMap :

```
for (MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(4).getObjects()
    .getByType(CircleMapObject.class)) {
    Circle circ = ((CircleMapObject) object).getCircle();

    new Coin(world,map,circ);
}
```

I think the problem is that you cant create Circles in the TiledMapEditor. I created Ellipses and gave them equal width and height, which should be a Circle, but apparently this doesnt work...
Any solutions or tips would be great!!

Comment: Retrieve them as EllipseMapObject.

Comment: How do I use the EllipseMapObject ? Any Example or tips?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66924/how-can-i-convert-a-tilemap-to-a-box2d-world